# Python : Flask importing a file from current directory, but subcategory

Tags: python

I'm struggling to import a folder that has many engines I need to use. I'm importing from `main_file.py`.
So I think I can use - `from engines import qr_code_gen`, but I need to import a class which is named  `_QRCode_` so I tried using - `from .engines.qr_code_gen import _QRCode_`, but it says "module engines was not found".

Structure:

```
Server/start.sh
Server/wsgi.py
Server/application/main_file.py
Server/application/engines/qr_code_gen.py
Server/application/engines/__init__.py
...
```

I used `sys.path` in `main_file.py` and I got -

> ['C:\Users\Dzitc\Desktop\winteka2',
>   'C:\Users\Dzitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\flask.exe',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.zip',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37',
>   'C:\Users\Dzitc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'c:\users\dzitc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in your `application ` directory?

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov yes

Comment: Is `winteka2` where you app is located?

Comment: What do you get if you just `import engines`?

Comment: yes @AzamatGalimzhanov, winteka2 is my project name, I found another import which I use in same directory, but it works fine - `from application.api.api_ipstack import _ipv4_`, I tried `application.engines.qr_code_gen`, but it doesn't work

Comment: 'engines' imported but unusedflake8(F401)

Comment: lmao, I change the name - 'engines' to - 'engine', moved the folder to `Server/application/api/` and used this import - `from application.api.engine.qr_code_gen import _QRCode_`, and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from comments you can import engine package.

Try this then:

```
import engines

engines.qr_code_gen._QRCode_
```